# SharePoint 2013 Performance Dashboard Designer not getting launched. Showing random behaviour

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, performancepoint, dashboard-designer-2013

I am working on PerformancePoint Services.

For that purpose I need to launch SharePoint Dashboard Designer. When I downloaded that designer file from the PerformancePoint library, and clicked on it it is giving an error as

> Ccannot download the application, the application is missing required files. Contact application vendor.

I got some solution for that, but it only worked temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience the dashboard designer is going to launch only from **Internet Explorer** (at least for me For SharePoint Server 2013).

Try the following :

Go to Site Contents -> PerformacePoint Content in your BI site and click on +new item

or

Click on PerformacePoint in the ribbon and choose Dashboard Designer.

I know that i am answering a very old question but it might help other users who have similar problem. Please mark it as accepted answer if you feel it solves your problem.